# DFT frequency subtraction

Tags: dft

If the maximum magnitude M = A^2 + B^2 of DFT transform corresponds to the frequency F, 
(A - real, B - imaginary output of DFT, at frequency F)
then is it correct to do the following:

```
for (j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
    data[j] -=  (A*cos(2*PI*F*j/dfts) -
                 B*sin(2*PI*F*j/dfts)) / dfts;
}
```

In order to cancel (subtract) that frequency influence from original wave data? 
The data is assumed to be a sum of several sines and cosines with different frequencies and multiplied by different coeffitients.

EDIT1:
I could achieve the cancelation by subtracting, and the result is correct. There was a mistake in above, but it is possible to do it. If interested I can post the way of doing it.

EDIT2:
And if you do the next DFT transform, you will get a very small, near zero value at the A and B values.
But you need to remember, that the original data can be the sum of 4 frequencies (sines and cosines) but the DFT transform will give you as much as the size of DFT is divided by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - that won't work. It could only work if the time domain component matched the FFT bin frequency *exactly* and the phase of the component is constant throughout the sample window, and even if this were the case you'd still need to take care of phase in your subtraction.

Ideally you need to remove (i.e. zero) the component in the frequency domain and then do an inverse FFT. Note that you probably don't want to just zero the bin of interest in the frequency domain, as this will produce artefacts in the time domain after you inverse FFT - you'll need to apply a window function to the bin of interest and adjacent bins.

Comment: Can I remove it by making that component equal to zero? What about the peaks that are near the F frequency at the graph of magnitude?

Comment: I think I've now covered this in my answer - I was still editing when you commented.

Comment: @maximus: zeroing the bin will remove all energy within the frequency range of that bin.

Comment: For example if the data consist of some exactly fitting (matching the FFT bin exactly) frequencies and some other non exactly fitting. For the exactly fitting frequency, will the method still be correct? Or the non exact frequencies will spoil everything?

Comment: About zeroing, as we know there are false peaks, going from the biggest peak, which, in turn, is the correct (almost) frequency included in the data. Zeroing the biggest peak will of cource as you said remove all energy withing the range of that bin, but the nearest bins still have values (energy)near the biggest peak, and other peaks too make an influence. So may be it is not so effitient to zero the only bin..

Comment: @maximum: in practice you will apply a windowed notch to the spectrum - this will be zero at the frequency bin of interest and will have smoothed values either side of this bin to reduce artefacts in the time domain (as I described in the answer above). You need to understand that the STFT only provides an *estimate* of the power spectrum - results will depend on how stationary your signal is.